# How do I initialize an empty string that can be inputted by the user in assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I tried 2 methods.

```
.model small
.stack 100
.data
var1 db 20 dup(?)
nl db 13,10, "$"
.code
main proc

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ah,0ah
lea dx,var1
int 21h

mov ah,09h
lea dx,nl
int 21h

mov ah,09h
lea dx,var1
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

which when compiled doesn't even prompt an input.

```
.model small
.stack 100
.data
var1 label byte
max db 20
act db ?
var1data db 19 dup ('$')
nl db 13,10, "$"


.code
main proc

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
;--output m1
mov ah,0ah
lea dx,var1
int 21h

mov ah,09h
lea dx,nl
int 21h

mov ah,09h
lea dx,var1
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

This outputs the string but with a few random extra chars in front.Additionally, I would like to get the actual size of the string.Neither of these methods give me an error or warning so what could be the solution?

Comment: The second version is better but you should use `lea dx,var1data` for printing. The actual length of the string is stored in the `act` variable.

Comment: @jester what if I had multiple arrays, how would the compiler know which ```act``` i'm referring to?

Comment: Obviously you can't use the same label for multiple buffers. The assembler would produce an error for that.

Comment: The ```var1data``` change works. Thank you. Regarding the ```act```variable. Do you mean I can rename it?

Comment: Of course. It's just a label like every other. Heck, you don't even need a label for it, if you are happy to reference it as `var1+1`. PS: telling DOS that your buffer is 20 bytes and then only allocating 19 which in reality is even just 18 doesn't sound like a good idea :)